# json file does not get edited by python

Tags: python, file-writing

i want to put the return of my API listener to a json file.
Unfortunately when i run the code below only the empty dictionary does get printed to the jsonfile.
I don't see why, does anyone know why it is like that?

```
from chessdotcom import get_player_game_archives
import pprint
import requests
import pymongo
import json

uName = input()
printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
global game 
game = {}

def get_most_recent_game(username):
    data = get_player_game_archives(username).json
    url = data['archives'][-1]
    games = requests.get(url).json()
    game = games['games'][-1]
    printer.pprint(game)
    return(game)

get_most_recent_game(uName)

with open('Games.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(game, json_file)
```

Comment: Looks like you need `game = get_most_recent_game(uName)`.

Comment: Also if you wanted `get_most_recent_game` to work with the global game object you would put `global game` inside the definition of `get_most_recent_game`.  As it is, it's better to avoid global variables.  I would just remove `game` as a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written, you (uselessly) declare the name `game` global in the global scope, not in the function scope.

```
def get_most_recent_game(username):
    global game
    data = get_player_game_archives(username).json
    url = data['archives'][-1]
    games = requests.get(url).json()
    game = games['games'][-1]
    printer.pprint(game)
    return(game)
```

However, if you are going to completely overwrite the value of `game` with a new value *and* return it anyway, there's no need to make `game` global in the first place.

```
uName = input()
printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

def get_most_recent_game(username):
    data = get_player_game_archives(username).json
    url = data['archives'][-1]
    games = requests.get(url).json()
    game = games['games'][-1]
    printer.pprint(game)
    return game 

game = get_most_recent_game(uName)

with open('Games.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(game, json_file)
```